# Angular/Material - Cannot read property 'run' of undefined - mat-sidenav-container

Tags: angular-material, angular-material2

I have managed to import angular/material into my project after prototyping a new front end on stackblitz, but for some reason the `<mat-sidenav-container>` and related components are throwing errors in console.

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/australia-greyhounds-ui-material-2iwn8a)**

> Cannot read property 'run' of undefined

[image]

Does anybody know of a solution?

Comment: Is this Angular 1 or 2/4?

Comment: @rrd - Material will only work with 5 ;-)

Comment: @physicsboy Can I see your Stackblitz?

Comment: Also, please don't use the [tag:javascript] tag.

Comment: @Edric - Updated my post with the link - Removed the JS tag - It actually works on StackBlitz...that's what is so puzzling?

Comment: What's your version of Angular?

Comment: @Edric - Upgraded to version 5 so that I could use Material. "@angular/core": "^5.2.2",

Comment: How about Angular Material?

Comment: @Edric - The latest: "@angular/material": "^5.1.1",

Comment: @physicsboy Can you try raising this as a bug at the Github repo? https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/new

Comment: @physicsboy That Stackblitz is working on my end.

Comment: Yeah, like I said... It works fine in the StackBlitz browser, but not when I port it out to my actual code... I have no idea why. I downloaded all of the same packages